# IDLE GUI is unable to give output

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-idle

```
Python 3.4.1 (v3.4.1:c0e311e010fc, May 18 2014, 10:45:13) [MSC v.1600 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> print "Harshit"
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Where is the problem here?

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to use Python 2.x syntax in Python 3.x.

In Python 3.x, `print` is no longer a statement.  Instead, it was [converted into function](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.0.html#print-is-a-function) and therefore must now be called like one:

```
>>> print("hi")  # Note the parenthesis
hi
>>>
```